Ubuntu 24.04 OS Install with RAID1 mdadm not working when using UEFI boot
I am trying to setup mdadm RAID1 for the os drive for ubuntu 24.04 lts and am not sure what is going on with uefi that it is adding mount points to one of the drives even though i want no partition on it so i can create the RAID1 on the 2 drives
please see the screenshot below

So i went ahead and set it up anyways and this how it looks
root@ubuntu:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sr0          11:0    1   16M  0 rom   
xvda        202:0    0   16G  0 disk  
├─xvda1     202:1    0  763M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─xvda2     202:2    0 15.3G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 15.2G  0 raid1 
    └─md0p1 259:0    0 15.2G  0 part  /
xvdb        202:16   0   16G  0 disk  
├─xvdb1     202:17   0  763M  0 part  
└─xvdb2     202:18   0 15.3G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 15.2G  0 raid1 
    └─md0p1 259:0    0 15.2G  0 part  /
xvdc        202:32   0   32G  0 disk  
xvde        202:64   0   32G  0 disk  
xvdf        202:80   0   32G  0 disk  
xvdg        202:96   0   32G  0 disk  

root@ubuntu:~# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Sep 13 07:18:25 2024
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 15984640 (15.24 GiB 16.37 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 15984640 (15.24 GiB 16.37 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Sep 13 07:50:20 2024
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : f3d46673:304110ea:067c80bd:d0415d2b
            Events : 87

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202        2        0      active sync   /dev/xvda2
       1     202       18        1      active sync   /dev/xvdb2

root@ubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           194M  1.1M  193M   1% /run
efivarfs        1.0G  1.5M 1023M   1% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/md0p1       15G  4.4G  9.8G  31% /
tmpfs           970M     0  970M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda1      762M  6.2M  756M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           194M   12K  194M   1% /run/user/1000

As you can see the boot partition is still pointing to the first partition of the first disk /dev/xvda
Is this not problematic? i think i will just avoid UEFI boot firmware altogether
Is this expected behavior and will this cause any issues later on?
setting up RAID1 i want both drives to be exactly same and right now efi will not let that happen
for example if the drive with the /boot/efi is the one that fails, i hope this wont be a problem when relying on the protection of RAID1 but it essentially setup for failure from the beginning
please share comments
